# Need help proving policy improvement theorem for epsilon greedy policies

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm slightly confused about the proof epsilon greedy policy improvement. This is a part of the proof:

$\begin{aligned}
q_{\pi}\left(s, \pi^{\prime}(s)\right) &=\sum_{a} \pi^{\prime}(a \mid s) q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+(1-\varepsilon) \max _{a} q_{\pi}(s, a) \\
& \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|} \sum_{a} q_{\pi}(s, a)+(1-\varepsilon) \sum_{a} \frac{\pi(a \mid s)-\frac{\varepsilon}{|\mathcal{A}(s)|}}{1-\varepsilon} q_{\pi}(s, a)
\end{aligned}$

I'm stuck on the very first line itself. Why is $q_{\pi}\left(s, \pi^{\prime}(s)\right) =\sum_{a} \pi^{\prime}(a \mid s) q_{\pi}(s, a)$? I've looked at other similar questions on this site, but they dont seem to address this line of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sutton describes it as a natural definition.

If we are at state $s$, we take action $a$ with probability $\pi'(a|s)$ according to policy $\pi'$ and we compute the expected value.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand why the action value of taking one action ($\pi'(s)$) in state $s$ is equal to the expectation of all action values in $s$.

Comment: it is not one action right, it is action $a$ with probability $\pi'(a|s)$.

Comment: Ohhh yes, I forgot that epsilon greedy policies may have multiple actions that can be chosen with the same probability. Thank you.